# How to connect the folder to Tortoise that is already checked out using command prompt

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I checked out my repository using "svn co ..." command. I see that there is a hidden .svn folder under. I am now using Tortoise and I want to update + commit using Tortoise. Is there any way to let the Tortoise know about the repository info? Apparently it doesn't know it because when I right click on the folder I see only Repo-browser, Properties, Settings, Help and About.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about Tortoise that makes it know whether a folder in under source control or not, so something else is wrong here.

On my tortoise, I don't have properties menu on uncontrolled folders, but I do have create repo here, import and export. Are your menu items just hidden in a sub menu?

Comment: That's the same. I mean I also have create repo here in uncontrolled folders. I don't have any sub menu.

Comment: well, I've just tried it - TSVN 1.8. From the cmd line, "svn co <repo url>". Then look at that folder in windows explorer and it has the green overlay and all the menus I'd expect for tortoise. You must have a broken working copy, can you checkin using the command line?